# Make a link as a button in rails spree

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, spree

I am working on a rails spree app.

I want to give my link work as a button. Here's how the link looks.

```
<li>
  <%= link_to Spree.t(:forgot_password), spree.recover_password_path %>
</li>
```

How do I make this as Button and add some classes to that button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate an HTML button, instead of a hyperlink then change your `link_to` to `button_to`:

```
<%= button_to Spree.t(:forgot_password), spree.recover_password_path %>
```

This will generate a form with a single button in it that would take user to a given URL.

However, if you want to **simply style** your link as a button, then use CSS. The CSS rules will depend on your style. So, just Google and pick a style that fits your needs.

If your template is using Twitter Bootstrap, you can simply add `btn` and `btn-*` classes to style it as a button.

```
<%= link_to Spree.t(:forgot_password), spree.recover_password_path, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
```

Comment: Damn! I was doing it but was missing the `comma` before the class. The second option is what I needed.

Thanks